# PowerShell function not accepting array of objects

Tags: function, powershell, parameters

In PowerShell, I have an array of objects that I need to pass to a function.  The function is to then loop through all of the objects in the array, but it seems that it is not accepting the parameter value correctly.

Take the following example, where I pass an array containing two objects.  I would expect the count of the array to be 2 both before the function and within the function, but as soon as it hits the function the count is 1, and my input is not as expected; only the last object is discovered.

Am I missing something here, or is this a bug in PowerShell?

## Example code

```
### I've also tries '[object]', '[array]' and '[array[]]' as the type for '$testArr'.
function Test-PassArrayOfObjects
{
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object[]]$testArr
    )
    Write-Host "In function count: $($testArr.Count)"
    $testArr | ForEach-Object { $_ }
}

$test1 = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
$test1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Test1 -Value Value1
$test2 = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
$test2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Test2 -Value Value2
$testArr = @($test1, $test2)

$testArr.GetType() | Format-Table
Write-Host "Before function count: $($testArr.Count)"
$testArr | Test-PassArrayOfObjects
```

## Output from example code

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----     --------                                                                                                                                                                                              
True     True     Object[] System.Array                                                                                                                                                                                          


Before function count: 2
In function count: 1

Test2 
----- 
Value2
```

## Working fix

Based on the answer below, I have this working example, which I've been able to apply to my real life scenario.

```
function Test-PassArrayOfObjects
{
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object]$testArr
    )
    Process {
        Write-Host "In function count: $($testArr.Count)"
        $testArr
    }
}

$test1 = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
$test1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Test1 -Value Value1
$test1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Test2 -Value Value2
$test2 = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
$test2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Test1 -Value Value1
$test2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Test2 -Value Value2
$testArr = @($test1, $test2)

$testArr.GetType() | Format-Table
Write-Host "Before function count: $($testArr.Count)"
$testArr | ForEach-Object { $_ | Test-PassArrayOfObjects }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When sending input to a function via the pipeline, your function should include a `Process` block:

```
function Test-PassArrayOfObjects
{
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object[]]$testArr
    )
    Process {
        Write-Host "In function count: $($testArr.Count)"
        $testArr | ForEach-Object { $_ }
    }
}
```

This is necessary because of the way the pipeline handles collections I believe. It automatically unrolls them and handles them one item at a time, so your `ForEach-Object` isn't getting the whole collection in the `$testArr` variable.

You often see functions like this still incorporate a `ForEach` though, in case the input is sent via a parameter in which case it is received all at once. For example: `Test-PassArrayOfObjects -TestArr @(1,2,3)`.

Your issue is further conflated by the fact that your array has two objects with different properties. This is creating confusion in the output because PowerShell decides how to format the output based on the first object and uses the same formatting when it outputs the second object, but then you don't see it because it doesn't share any of the same properties (I think this is what is occurring anyway..).

You can see that both objects get processed by putting `| Format-List` on the `$_` which forces both outputs to be formatted as list output independently. Note that this isn't good practice in a real function scenario of course. An alternative is to make the property name on both objects `Test1`. Then you will see the output you probably expected without using `Format-List`.

Comment: Many thanks for your swift reply. I have just discovered [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/1327be63-2093-439d-8475-cf571e322efe/function-to-accept-array-from-pipe?forum=winserverpowershell) about exactly what you suggest.  In reality, all objects do contain the same properties, so that's not an issue, but I am doing some more complex processing, so simply adding the `process` block didn't fix my issue.  However, your explaination has led me to instead pass inidvidual objects to the function, and I'm now able to format the output as desired.

Comment: "You often see functions like this still incorporate a ForEach though, in case the input is sent via a parameter in which case it is received all at once"
I find this confusing. What is the best practice? Also confused by whether or not the param type should be declared as an array or not.